# Python Console GUI Updating whilst getting keyboard input

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, input

I was wondering if it is possible to have a command-line interface that in essence blinks the current system time every second but allows the user to keep entering data via raw_input or something?

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: What does "blinks the current system" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not at the same time anyway. Here's an example for showing the time in terminal.

```
import time
while True:
    #time.sleep(1) #Uncommet to have it only print the time every second
    x = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print x
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't think I could